# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am getting this error in the console which is not letting me perform my task of fetching the values into the datatable. I will post my code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var product_id = '<?php echo $product->product_id; ?>';
    var table = $('table.container-fluid').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "agent/order/getProduct",
            "data": { "pid": product_id }
        },
    });
    $('#selectProduct').click(function() {
        var id = $("#selectproduct").val();
        var product = ('agent/order/getProduct?product_id=' + id);
        table.ajax.url(product).load();
        table.reload();
    });
```

Below please find the controller code:

```
public function getProduct () {
    $prod_id = $this->input->post('pid');
    $this->load->model('order_m');
    $prod = $this->order_m->getProductById($prod_id);
    echo json_encode($prod);
}
```

In chrome when I check the issue, it points out to this: `table.ajax.url(product).load();`

Can anybody please help me with this issue?

Comment: `table.ajax` is null or undefined. What do you see when you `console.log(table)`?

Comment: I believe it is undefined.

Comment: That's what the error says.

Comment: `[object Object]` that is what I get on `alert(table)`

Comment: Do not alert, use `console.log(table)` instead to see object properties.

Comment: `[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "table.container-fluid", oApi: Object]` this is what I get on `console.log(table);`

Comment: you need `var table = $('table.container-fluid').dataTable({`, you simply forget to save the datatable instance into a variable, even though you are referencing to it later on.

Comment: I am not sure, what you mean exactly, but I have added that as as `var table = $('table.container-fluid');` and called `table.dataTable({...});` Later on

Comment: @davidnoronha, I have edited the code in the question so it looks like what I meant above (you can always rollback or re-edit) - now you have a `table` instance and you will not get a `'url' of undefined` because `table.ajax` now actually is defined.

Comment: @davidkonrad I have included the code in your edit. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

In DataTables 1.10 naming convention has changed, see [API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/) for more information.

You need to initialize your table as `$("#logTable").dataTable()` with lower case `d` to get access to previous version API or with `$("#logTable").DataTable()` with upper case `D` to get access to newer API.

Initialize your table using `DataTable()` not `dataTable()` as shown below:

```
var table = $('table.container-fluid').DataTable({
    // ... skipped ...
});
```

Alternatively, if you need to have access to older API and initialize with `dataTable()`, you can call newer API methods as shown below:

```
var table = $('table.container-fluid').dataTable({
    // ... skipped ...
});

table.api().ajax.url(newURL).load();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, but that did not help. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @davidnoronha, You have another error in your code, there is no `reload()` method, use [`ajax.reload()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29) instead.

Comment: @davidnoronha, there is no need for `ajax.reload` at all, since you are using [`ajax.url().load()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url%28%29.load%28%29) which is the same thing in your case.

Comment: @davidnoronha, this is unrelated but you also have server-side processing enabled with `serverSide: true`. In this mode sorting, searching and ordering should be performed on the server. Is this what you're doing?

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sorry for the late reply. It is fetching the data from the database in phpmyadmin. I guess the `serverSide: true` would be required right?

Comment: The `table.api()` did not help. The error after adding that was `table.api is not a function`. Trying with `table.reload()` also does the same ie `table.reload is not a function`

Comment: @davidnoronha Did u finally get the solution. Even I am stuck in the same thing. Could you please tell me what worked for you. Thanks.